# MATLAB - Find and number duplicates within an array

Tags: matlab, unique

I have an array of values, some of which have duplicates, for example:

```
a = [5;5;4;7;7;3;3;9;5;7]
```

and I would like to find which are duplicates, and then number each of these sequentially, while making non-duplicates zero. For example:

```
b = [1;1;0;2;2;3;3;0;1;2]
```

Currently I have a very inefficient and incomplete approach, using the `unique` function and various `for` loops and `if` statements, but feel that there should be a simple answer.

What is the most efficient way to get to this answer?

Comment: Is an input like `[5;5;4;7;7;3;3;9;5;5;4;7]` possible? What would the result be?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, that input is also possible. I've modified the question to include non-consecutive duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a two liner that will also work for non consecutive duplicates

```
[c, ia, ic] = unique(a, 'stable');
[~, b] = ismember(a, a(ia(accumarray(ic,1)>1)));
```

I have used some ideas from [@excaza answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572832/7510661) with modifications.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach:

```
a = [5;5;4;7;7;3;3;9;5;7];
[u, ~, w] = unique(a, 'stable');
s = find(sum(bsxfun(@eq, a, u.'), 1) > 1);
b = sum(bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@eq, w, s), 1:numel(s)), 2);
```

In R2016b onwards you can simplify the syntax:

```
a = [5;5;4;7;7;3;3;9;5;7];
[u, ~, w] = unique(a, 'stable');
s = find(sum(a==u.', 1) > 1);
b = sum((w==s).*(1:numel(s)), 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), and [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to make the necessary adjustments:

```
a = [5;5;4;7;7;3;3;9];

% Identify unique values and their counts
[uniquevals, ~, ia] = unique(a, 'stable');  % Stable keeps it in the same order
bincounts = accumarray(ia, 1);  % Count the frequency of each index in ia

% Zero out singles
singles = uniquevals(bincounts <= 1);
[~, singleidx] = intersect(a, singles);
a(singleidx) = 0;

% Overwrite repeats
repeats = uniquevals(bincounts > 1);
[~, a] = ismember(a, repeats);
```

Which returns a new `a` of:

```
a =

     1     1     0     2     2     3     3     0
```

---

## Walkthrough

We use `unique` here to find all of the unique values in our input array, `a`. We also store the optional third output, which is a mapping of the values of `a` to their index in the array of unique values. Note that we're using the `stable` option to obtain the unique values in the order they're first encountered in `a`; the results of `unique` are sorted by default.

We then use `accumarray` to accumulate the subscripts we got from `unique`, which gives us a count of each index. Using [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1), we use these counts first to zero out the single instances. After these are zeroed out, we can <s>abuse</s> use the second output of `ismember` to return the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on indexing, logical operators  and [cumsum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
x = [false; a(2:end)==a(1:end-1)]; %logical indexes of repeated elements except the first element of each block 
y = [x(2:end)|x(1:end-1) ;x(end)]; %logical indexes of repeated elements
result = cumsum(~x&y).*y           %cumsum(...):number all elements sequentially and (... .* y): making non-duplicates zero
```

**Edit:**

As the question edited, to manipulate non-consecutive duplicates you can do this:

```
[s ii] = sort(a);
x = [false ;s(2:end)==s(1:end-1)];
y = [x(2:end)|x(1:end-1) ;x(end)];
first = ~x&y;
[~,ix]=sort(ii(first));
un(ix,1)=1:numel(ix);
result(ii,1)=un(cumsum(first)).*y;
```

Comment: I like this effective approach. This finds only consecutive duplicates though.

Comment: @Y.Chang Thanks! It seems that OP wants consecutive duplicates except that I receive a new feedback.

Comment: Can't say where exactly the problem is, but your second approach bugs if more than 2 same elements exist. E.g. for `a = [5;5;5;4;7;7;3;3;3;3;9];
` . Still very neat tough.

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger Thanks, you are right, the second approach removed.